# Difference between size of input and output image for 2D-DCT

Tags: python, image, image-processing, dct, image-preprocessing

I am working on epilepsy seizure prediction classification. First, I preprocess my dataset using 2D-DCT, I apply 2D-DCT on each image of size(22,7680), I found that the output of 2D-DCT has the same size as the input image I wonder if that right.

Any help would be appreciated.

**my code:**

```
normalized_image=preprocessing.normalize(input_image)
result=fftpack.dct(fftpack.dct(normalized_image.T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
```

Answer (score 0):

DCT bases form a complete and orthogonal set, so the input and output of this transformation should have same number of samples or same size.